# Stop/Break looping from server side with client side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api, rest

I have async job inside looping from server side:

```
const contacts = [];

for(contact of contacts){
    (async () => {
        await MailService.sendMessage(contact, 'message body')
    })()
}
```

I want to break that looping using client side, what i do is:

1 . from server side, before sendMessage, check if **Broadcast** status is **process** or **stopped**, if stopped, than break looping.

2 . from client side, if i want to stop the Broadcast(stop looping), i need to update Broadcast value from process to stopped.

So, my code should be:

server side:

```
const contacts = [];

for(contact of contacts){
    (async () => {
        const currentBroadcast = await Broadcast.findById('id')
        if(currentBroadcast.status === 'stopped') break;

        await MailService.sendMessage(contact, 'message body')
    })()
}
```

client side:

```
document.getElementById('stop').addEventListener('click', () => {
    fetch('url/broadcast/stop/:id')
})
```

it works. But wouldn't that make the server heavy? Because in every loop I have to check into the database.

is there any other way i can do to stop the looping? without having to check into the database.

Comment: If the server is running continuously you could simple store the state of the element in memory. Furthermore, to persist the data, you can save it to the db every x minutes. If the server restarts, load the values into the memory and use it as in memory database. This answer only covers your question about "the query of the db in every loop".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a database for that - you just need to update a value that can be seen in the server's code. You could have a plain Express route that adds client session IDs to a collection, which gets updated when the route is called. Then, just have your loop check whether that client's sent such a request.

With [sessions](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/session.html), you could have something like, with a route:

```
const stoppedBroadcastSessionIds = new Set();
app.post('/stopbroadcast', function (req, res) {
  stoppedBroadcastSessionIds.add(req.session.id);
})
```

and then do

```
for(const contact of contacts){
  if (stoppedBroadcastSessionIds.has(req.session.id)) break;
  await MailService.sendMessage(contact, 'message body')
}
```

Comment: aaaah thanks, i will use this method, i dont need to use database anymore